# 'super' object has no attribute '_get_type_value'

Tags: python, odoo

I have created a customized module for Sales CRM in OpenERP.  While creating opportunity when I click on stage field, it gives me the following error:

```
list = super(crm_stage_claim, self)._get_type_value(cr, user, context)
```

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_get_type_value'

Any Help on this would be appreciated.

Regards
sameer

Comment: Are we helping you with code you wrote, or the software itself?

Comment: Avoid using variable names like 'list', 'str', 'dict', 'float', 'int' etc. which mask the native Python types.

Comment: Is `crm_stage_claim` a class or an instance? By convention, class names are written as CamelCaseLikeThis, not underscore_separated_like_this. This is why following standard naming conventions will help *you* - when you ask others for help, they can make reasonable assumptions about your code without wasting a lot of your time and theirs with silly questions like 'is crm_stage_claim a class or an instance?'

Comment: More context for your code would be helpful. If it's committed to a branch on launchpad, add a link to the code so people can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure:

- crm_stage_claim extends crm.case.stage
- crm.case.stage inherits from object (is a new-style class, which
  supports super)
- you have not overridden super by assigning something else to it,
  masking the Python builtin
- crm.case.stage does in fact have a _get_type_value method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the base class of the crm_stage_claim has no attribute `_get_type_value` method.

Comment: The class 'crm_stage_claim' has a '_get_type_value' method inherited from the crm.case.stage.

Comment: No,crm_stage_claim class contains _get_type_value method ,inherited from crm.case.stage

Answer (score 0):

Check that your module code has access to the `crm_stage_claim` class. In most modules, you don't have direct access to the other modules, you only have access to the server classes like `osv.osv`. You can access *instances* of other modules' classes by using the `pooler` class, but I'm not sure if you can get the right types that way.